# Using array entry as href to website

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, href

I've made an array with several entries for a database (at now just two, but it will become a lot more). Just one of the entries (homepage) shall be a link to a homepage and i have some trouble displaying it as a functional hyperlink. Just using:

```
      <a href="{{arrayEntryWithLink}}">linkName</a>
```

won't work and i've read that i have to use innerHtml, but to be honest i don't know how to use it in a proper way. 
Would be great if someone could give me a short explanation or an example how to use it correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the

#### .js:

```
$scope.Biere=[
  {name:'Jever Pilsener',   
   Bierart:'Untergärig',
   Honk:'6',
   Bitterkeit:'7',
   Sauerkeit:'3',
   Kohle:'5',
   brew: 'Friesisches Brauhaus zu Jever',

homepage: 'http://www.jever.de',

   description: '...',
   temperatur: '10-12°'
},
  {name:'Erdinger Weißbier', 
   Bierart:'Obergärig',
   Honk:'5',
   Bitterkeit:'3',
   Sauerkeit:'4',
   Kohle:'6',
   brew: 'Privatbrauerei Erdinger Weißbräu',

homepage: 'http://www.erdinger.de',

   description: '...',
   temperatur: '14-15°'
 },
];
```

And the

#### .html

```
               <table class="table">
                    <tr ng-repeat="bier in Biere">
                        <td><h3>{{bier.name}}</h3>
                        </br>
                            Süffigkeit: {{bier.Honk}}</br>
                            Bitterkeit: {{bier.Bitterkeit}}</br>
                            Kohlensäure: {{bier.Kohle}}</br>
                            Sauer: {{bier.Sauerkeit}}</br>
                            Brauerei: {{bier.brew}}</br>

                    Homepage: <a href="{{bier.homepage}}">{{bier.homepage}}</a></br>

                            Trinktemperatur: {{bier.temperatur}}</br>
                            {{bier.description}}</br>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Suggest you put your code into a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) demo. `bier` is not the same as `Biere` and `Biere` is an array not an object. If you have an `ng-repeat` for the array it is not shown in the question

Comment: You're right Sir, i forgot the ng-repeat. Also try to build it into jsFiddle but at the Moment it don't work if i just extract the upper code

Comment: Ok..so do the homepage values include `http://`? If not they will appear to browser as `http://yourSite.com/www.usersSite.com`. Should use `ng-href` but that won't fix problem if `href` isn't working either. If it is `http://` issue...that has nothing to do with angular... it is the way browsers work

Comment: Well, i forgot the http:// in the code above, too. But it was in the original.  Tried ng-href and now it works! Thanks a lot mate! Maybe could you explain when to use href / ng-href? I read about it but... i think don't got the hole thing.

Comment: use `ng-href` when data won't exist right away, or may be undefined. Prevents user clicking on `<a href="{{}}">` before angular compiles or for after compiled `<a href="">` if value isn't set. Easiest to use it all the time in angular

Comment: Okay, now i understand. As you can see my english is not the best and i'm not very familiar with the hole thing. Thank you for this noob-friendly explanation!